Chartink website scanner to google sheets api script without using python
I need help to get data in google sheets from Chartink website scanner, using google sheets api script without using python.
sheet1 A10 is having url link, when I did the inspection of the site using developers tools - Network tab - XHR - payload.
It has scan query and debug query as per the code below - I am not getting desired outout.
I wish to have below but above is simple ask.
the url is in ((input)) sheet cell A1,
payload is in scan query: is in b1,
payload debug query: is in c1
I am looking for output in ((output)) sheet A1.
function Chartinkupload() {
  // Get the URL from cell A10 of the active sheet
  const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A10").getValue();

  // Prepare the payload data (consider adding comments to explain each part)
  const payloadData = {
    "scan_clause": "( {33492} ( latest volume > 1 day ago volume and latest close > 200 ) )",
    "debug_clause": "groupcount( 1 where daily volume > 1 day ago volume),groupcount( 1 where daily close > 200)"
  };

  // Convert payload to JSON string
  const payload = JSON.stringify(payloadData);

  try {
    // Send POST request with JSON payload
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      payload: payload,
      contentType: "application/json"
    });

    // Check for successful response
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      const json = response.getContentText();
      const chartinkData = JSON.parse(json);
      Logger.log(chartinkData);
    } else {
      Logger.log("Error fetching data: " + response.getResponseCode());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error during upload: " + error.message);
  }
}


Hi @cooper - https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper,  I found your reply to a question similar to mine, really need your help.

I am getting error -----Error during upload: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Personally I prefer using chrome snippets to get data from websites.  You can generally copy data to the console as a 2d array with incurring the wrath of their security software and then paste it into a spreadsheet.

@Cooper thanks for your suggestion, I started to explore and wish it to to when I saw a post in youtube, I communicated with the person but he is not ready to reveal how he did just that he is not using any extension or python he did it just using google sheets api script, wondering how he must have done, I tried many a times but dont know how to fix, when I searched on google found your reply.....if you can have a look, am I wrong somewhere is it possible doing it only using Javascript

The problem with using your approach is that the data is often not on the opening page.  It's often loaded via javascript after the initial rendering which necessitates the use of a headless browser.   So that's why I prefer  the use of snippects
